# Getting Permission denied error while mounting file

Tags: centos, centos7, mount

I am trying to mount a file on CentOS7 based on windows but I am getting mount error 13 permission denied error.

I have created a shared folder on Windows C folder and given access to all users .Also I have created a mount point on CentOS whose path is /usr/local/qdc/qvdshare.

Below is the code used in /etc/fstab

//192.168.1.151/qvd-share /usr/local/qdc/qvdshare cifs file_mode=0444,dir_mode=0444,user,credentials=/root/.credentials,rw,uid=500,gid=500,noperm, 0 0

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem and spent so much time figuring it out.
In my case it ended up being a line feed issue. You need to make sure that your file /root/credentials has the right termination for lines. If it was created with a windows editor, the line feed are most likely CRLF instead of LF. In Windows both a CR and LF are required to note the end of a line, whereas in Linux/UNIX a LF is only required.

Solution would be to try creating the credentials file directly in linux via your favorite command line editor, and try to mount again.